# Can I clip background image a few pixels?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a repeating pattern for a background image. It's a series of diagonal lines. The pattern doesn't quite line up when the images are tiled in a background. Do I have to go in and edit the image to get them to line up, or is there a way to "clip" them using the `background-` CSS attributes?

```css
h2 {
      margin: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .orange-title-bar {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }
    .orange-title-bar:before, .orange-title-bar:after {
      background: url(../images/patterns/Pattern-YELLOW.png);
      content: '';
      flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
<span class="orange-title-bar">
      <h2>
        Title
      </h2>
    </span>
```

Comment: screenshot please

Comment: If you have a choice I would rather edit the image to make it fit your need and if the image is used in many places, make a copy of it, change it and use that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might prefer to simply "move" the image a little in its container:

```
background: url(../images/patterns/Pattern-YELLOW.png) 5px 10px;
```

for example?